# Can I "lock" a value type like this? Is there any better solution?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Example Code (I use Semaphore rather than lock to "lock" that bool member):

```cs
public class MsgSendHandler
{
    private bool _isSocketSending = false;
    private Semaphore _socketSendingSem = new Semaphore(1, 1);

    public void Send(INetMsg msg)
    {
        // Add Msg To MsgQueue
        TrySendNext();
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Finish Send
        _socketSendingSem.WaitOne();
        _isSocketSending = false;
        _socketSendingSem.Release();
        TrySendNext();
    }

    private bool TrySendNext()
    {
        _socketSendingSem.WaitOne();
        if (_isSocketSending)
            return false;

        _isSocketSending = true;
        _socketSendingSem.Release();
        // Socket Begin Send => SendCallback
        return true;
    }
}
```

Can I "lock" a value type like this? Is there any better solution?

Comment: The way I created mutli-threaded functionality in Unity3D was to have a Dispatcher class that is called once per frame to run any Actions that have been added to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on comment:

The way I created mutli-threaded functionality in Unity3D was to have a Dispatcher class that is called once per frame to run any Actions that have been added to a list.

**Dispatcher.cs**
A simple singleton class that holds the actions with an actual lock when looping through the actions.

```
public class Dispatcher
{
    private static Dispatcher _instance;
    public static Dispatcher Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new Dispatcher();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private List<Action> _actions = new List<Action> ();

    public void AddAction(Action action)
    {
        lock (_actions)
        {
            _actions.Add(action);
        }
    }

    public void CompleteActions()
    {
        lock (_actions)
        {
            foreach (Action action in _actions)
            {
                action();
            }
        }
        _actions.Clear();
    }

    public void ClearActions()
    {
        lock (_actions)
        {
            _actions.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

**DispatcherUpdate.cs**
Another simple class that's added to a GameObject within the scene to call the Dispatcher to Complete the aquired Actions.

```
public class DispatcherUpdate : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    private void Awake()
    {
        Dispatcher.Instance.ClearActions();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Dispatcher.Instance.CompleteActions();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Dispatcher.Instance.AddAction(() => TrySendNext());
```

This is the method I've used for Async multi-threading with SignalR

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's a great practice sometimes. However, there is about 16ms between two frames(60 PFS). I want to send messages as soon as well, especially when I develop a FPS game.

Comment: You could change the `Update` to `LateUpdate` in DispatcherUpdate.cs and then it will be called that frame just at the end once the queue has been filled, that way it is runnning that frames queue not the queue from the previous